# How to select id from the datatables using checkbox

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Heres my code: HTML with Server side to get data from the database. How do I get id from the datatables using checkbox option?

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">

       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
       <thead>
       <tr>
       <h4>
       <th></th> <!-- For checkbox column-->
       <th>ID Number</th>
       <th>Lastname</th>                                          
       <th>Firstname</th>
       <th>Middlename</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
       <th>Course</th>
       <th>Department</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>Contact</th>
       <th>Birthdate</th>
       <th>View</th>
       <th>Events</th>


       </h4>
       </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>

       <?php
       include 'pgconnect.php';
       $mydata = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM student") or die(mysql_error());
           while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mydata)) 
              { 
                 $id=$record['id'];
         ?>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td class="id"><?php echo  $record['id'] ?></td>
        <td class="lname"><?php echo $record['last_name'] ?></td>
        <td class="fname"><?php echo $record['first_name'] ?></td>
        <td class="mname"><?php echo $record['mid_name'] ?></td>
        <td class="sex"><?php echo $record['gender'] ?></td>
        <td class="course"><?php echo $record['course'] ?></td>
        <td class="dept"><?php echo $record['department'] ?></td>                                             
        <td class="add"><?php echo $record['home_address'] ?></td>
        <td class="contact"><?php echo $record['contact'] ?></td>
        <td class="bdate"><?php echo $record['birthdate'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="records1.php?id="> View Records </a> </td>
        <td> <a  title='Click here to update record.'href='#edit' data-toggle='modal'><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i></a>
             <a title='Click here to add record.' href='#'><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i></a>
             <a title='Click here to delete record.' href='delete.php?del=<?php echo $record['id'] ?>'><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
           }
         ?>  
       </tbody> 

  </table>
```

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
    });
```

I tried to get the ID but still it didn't works. Hope you can help me.

[image: Here's the GUI of my system]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your work, you get the ID in table. your should grab it from the checkbox if you use jquery, as in;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
         document.getElementByID("ckmyid").innerHTML;
    });
</script>
```

Note:add Selector ID in your checkbox, first, say, "ckmyid" so the code will be like this:

```
<input id="ckmyid" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo  $record['id'] ?>">
```

Based on your structure, you can grab it directly from the link in your *view records* link if you want to place the ID there,as in;

```
<td><a href="records1.php?id=<?php echo  $record['id'] ?>"> View Records </a> </td>
```

Comment: very pleased to help you :*